# Conan + cmake + boost python

Tags: cmake, conan

I have just started using conan from my cmake files to download and build dependencies - very convenient. I have tried using it also for Boost, but the default conanfile for boost does not seem to build boost python which I need. My current setup looks like:

```
conan_cmake_configure(REQUIRES
  fmt/8.0.1
  boost/1.75.0
  eigen/3.4.0
  GENERATORS cmake_find_package)

conan_cmake_autodetect(settings)

conan_cmake_install(PATH_OR_REFERENCE .
  BUILD missing
  REMOTE conancenter
  SETTINGS ${settings})

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS Python) // Approx syntax
...
```

and this fails because the Boost python package is not available. I guess I can edit the `conan_make_configures()` command to make sure boost Python is built?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `OPTIONS` variable of `conan_cmake_configure`:

```
conan_cmake_configure(REQUIRES
  fmt/8.0.1
  boost/1.75.0
  eigen/3.4.0
  GENERATORS cmake_find_package
  OPTIONS boost:without_python=False
)
```

See: [https://github.com/conan-io/conan_cmake_configure](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan#conan_cmake_configure)

You can find all available options for boost package at: [boost C/C++ Package - JFrog ConanCenter](https://conan.io/center/boost?tab=configuration&os=)

**[Edit 1]: Use of a `conanfile` with cmake-conan**

You can also create a `conanfile.txt` to manage your dependencies:

```
[requires]
fmt/8.0.1
boost/1.75.0
eigen/3.4.0

[options]
boost:without_python=False

[generators]
cmake_find_package
cmake_paths
```

And call `conan_cmake_run` as follows:

```
conan_cmake_autodetect(settings)

conan_cmake_run(
        CONANFILE conanfile.txt
        BASIC_SETUP CMAKE_TARGETS
        BUILD missing
        SETTINGS ${settings}
)
```